# Okteto Up not able to replace Kubernetes resource

Tags: kubernetes, okteto

we are using okteto to allow development on the Kubernetes Cluster that runs locally.
We first deploy our Microservice and all of its resources using helm upgrade --install ... command. After the service is running,
we call okteto up, expecting that the microservice pod will be replaced by the okteto-manged microservice pod, as it is described in the documentation.
This however is not happening, due to the error "Resource [pod name] already exist".
These are the okteto logs:

```
"'.stignore' exists in folder '/home/vanja/dev/workspaces/ris-administration'" action=fc689dfc-1f1d-4942-901b-f7f2a037eea8 version=1.15.3

"Terminal: &{{1280 5 191 35387 0 [3 28 127 21 4 0 1 0 17 19 26 0 18 15 23 22 0 0 0] 0 0}}" action=fc689dfc-1f1d-4942-901b-f7f2a037eea8 version=1.15.3

"activating development container retry=false" action=fc689dfc-1f1d-4942-901b-f7f2a037eea8 version=1.15.3

"starting shutdown sequence" action=fc689dfc-1f1d-4942-901b-f7f2a037eea8 version=1.15.3

"sent cancellation signal" action=fc689dfc-1f1d-4942-901b-f7f2a037eea8 version=1.15.3

"stopping forwarders" action=fc689dfc-1f1d-4942-901b-f7f2a037eea8 version=1.15.3

"completed shutdown sequence" action=fc689dfc-1f1d-4942-901b-f7f2a037eea8 version=1.15.3

"activate failed with: resource administration already exist" action=fc689dfc-1f1d-4942-901b-f7f2a037eea8 version=1.15.3

"exit signal received due to error: resource administration already exist" action=fc689dfc-1f1d-4942-901b-f7f2a037eea8 version=1.15.3

"error deleting deprecated volume: persistentvolumeclaims \"okteto-administration\" not found" action=fc689dfc-1f1d-4942-901b-f7f2a037eea8 version=1.15.3
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards, Vanja

Comment: Check that you don't have the `autocreate` flag set to true on your `okteto.yaml`file.  If that doesn't fix it, can you post the contents of your `okteto.yaml` file?

Comment: that just solved the problem.